# What is the meaning of the following assembler-code line?

Tags: assembly, x86

I´ve written the following code in C to let create assembler code from that and to learn something about assembler.

I start with a hello world of course, and in one line, there is following:

```
    mov DWORD PTR[esp], OFFSET FLAT:.LCO
```

and about `LC0`, it says:

```
    .string "Hello World!"
    .text
    .globl main
    .type main,@function
```

So, and I asked myself, what the meaning of line with `OFFSET FLAT:.LCO` ?
Am I right, when I say, that something like a pointer which points to the string is given to `esp`? So that `esp` is now pointing to the string hello world, too?

Is that right? Because this would be logical.

Answer (score 4):

```
mov DWORD PTR[esp], OFFSET FLAT:.LCO
```

Moves the 4 bytes, that is the address specified .LCO to the memory location specified by ESP.

- .LCO is the memory address where the string "Hello World!" beings.
- ESP is the top of the stack, this code assumes that the value in ESP is a memory location
- The "FLAT" refers to the address space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model
- **.text** signals the beginning of the code segment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment